# What is f.gets.chomp doing? (Learn Ruby Hard Way: Exercise 20)

Tags: ruby, string, file-io

Link to the exercise: http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex20.html

I'm having trouble understanding the output of the exercise where it displays:

```
1, This is line 1
2, This is line 2
3, This is line 3
```

I don't understand which part of the code is causing the program to read the specific # of line. How does it know to read line 1 vs line 2 vs line 3?

Does it have something to do with this part:

```
def print_a_line(line_count, f)
    puts "#{line_count}, #{f.gets.chomp}"
end
```

I thought gets.chomp is for getting the user input from commandline (and cut off the line break).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`IO#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-gets) return a line (as a string) from a file with newline intact. (`f.gets` in the code). Every time you call it, it return next line from the file.

[`String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chomp) return a new string without the trailing newline:

```
"This is line 1\n".chomp
# => "This is line 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

On the side note chomp method can also remove end of the string if you give it a string as an argument it will remove it and return a new string `"hello".chomp("o") >> "hell"`